# Centrally aligned CSS animation is not symmetrical despite setting width:100% left:0

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, animation, css-animations

I'm using bootstrap 5.0.2

Animation of a button suppose to resize button symmetricaly from center to both left and right to 100% available width. It doesn't work as suppose to because it goes beyond the lines of symmetry (right size is too wide)

I don't understand why because:

```
<!--bootstrap-->

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!--code-->

<div class="container bg-success">
  <div class="border border-dark">

    <div class="row m-2 w-animate">
      <a target="_blank" href="velo-art" class="btn bg-animate border border-dark rounded-pill fs-1 col-12  text-center p-2">
        test
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="row m-2 w-animate">
      <a target="_blank" href="velo-art" class="btn bg-animate border border-dark rounded-pill fs-1 col-12  text-center p-2">
        test_2
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="row m-2 w-animate">
      <a target="_blank" href="velo-art" class="btn bg-animate border border-dark rounded-pill fs-1 col-12  text-center p-2">
        test_3
      </a>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>

<style>
.w-animate {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  animation: center-animate 3s ease infinite alternate;
}
.w-animate:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes center-animate {
  0% {
    width: 50%;
    left: 25%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0%;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hyzec5wr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent `<div>` of each `<a>`nchor has `m-2` class which is `margin: 0.5rem` (See **Figure I**).

**Figure I**

```html
                            <!-- ⬍ 0.5rem -->
<!-- ⬌ 0.5rem --> <div class="row m-2 w-animate"></div> <!-- ⬌ 0.5rem -->
                            <!-- ⬍ 0.5rem -->
```

So there are left and right margins that offset the actual position of the `<div>`s hence the asymmetrical behavior. Change each `m-2` class to `mx-0` to remove the left and right margins and add `my-2` in order to preserve the `0.5rem` between each `<div>` (See example below).

The following example has:

- class `m-2` assigned to the first `<div>`
- class `mx-1` and `my-2` assigned to the second `<div>`
- class `mx-0` and `my-2` assigned to the third `<div>`

Note the difference in offset from each of their center position. The third `<div>` is the correct class to use. Also note that the second and third `<div>` has `my-2` which is `margin: 0.5rem 0` (top and bottom margins at `0.5rem`). FYI the example also shows how a complete Bootstrap document should be arranged.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    .w-animate {
      position: relative;
      width: 50%;
      animation: center-animate 1s ease infinite alternate;
    }
    
    .w-animate:hover {
      animation-play-state: paused;
    }
    
    @keyframes center-animate {
      0% {
        width: 50%;
        left: 25%;
      }
      100% {
        width: 100%;
        left: 0%;
      }
    }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container bg-success">
    <div class="border border-dark">
      <div class="row m-2 w-animate">
        <a target="_blank" href="velo-art" class="btn bg-animate border border-dark rounded-pill fs-1 col-12  text-center p-2">
         m-2
      </a>
      </div>
      <div class="row mx-1 my-2 w-animate">
        <a target="_blank" href="velo-art" class="btn bg-animate border border-dark rounded-pill fs-1 col-12  text-center p-2">
          mx-1 my-2
      </a>
      </div>
      <div class="row mx-0 my-2 w-animate">
        <a target="_blank" href="velo-art" class="btn bg-animate border border-dark rounded-pill fs-1 col-12  text-center p-2">
          mx-0 my-2
      </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```